# Replaced certificate and now Apache server will not start up

Tags: apache2, httpd

So we are running an apache server on CentOS7 and the certificate for one of our sites expired. We replaced the certificate with the new one we received from DigiCert and went to restart the apache server.

However every time we try we get this error: "Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service and journalctl -xe" for details

So when I run the sysctl status  httpd.service -l command I am getting this description:

[Error Code Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91MQy.png)

I have done counbtless google searches but I just dont have enough information on the problem to get anywhere. Any ideas as to what could be stopping the server from starting?

Comment: Some tips on troubleshooting:
1) Can you place back your old expired certificate to the original location and see if the sever starts up fine? If not, the problem may be unrelated
2) Check that the new certificate is in the right format for Apache. It may need to be converted if it was issued for example for an IIS server
3) Double check the file permissions on the new certificate file and make sure the user that is running Apache has sufficient permissions on the file and path